# How do I edit CustomTrackShape?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am designing a custom track shape for a project that looks like this:
[image]

and I already finished most of the code, I ended up with this result:

[image]

aside from the rounded sides (those I'll fix), I need to achieve:

1. Move the label under
2. Change the label dimensions if possible
3. Customize the trackheight to make it smaller on one end and larger on the other.

Answer (score 1):

In short:
Wrap your *Slider*() inside a *SliderTheme*() and provide it with proper *SliderThemeData*() containing a **custom track shape** and a **custom thumb shape**.

#### CustomTrackShape()

```
class CustomTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {

  const CustomTrackShape({
  });

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required final RenderBox parentBox,
    required final SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    final bool isDiscrete = true,
    final bool isEnabled = true,
    final Offset offset = Offset.zero,
  }) {
    final double overlayWidth =
        sliderTheme.overlayShape!.getPreferredSize(isEnabled, isDiscrete).width;
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight ?? 20;
    final double trackLeft = offset.dx + overlayWidth / 2;
    final double trackTop =
        offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    // Although this works for a material, perhaps the default
    // rectangular track should be padded not just by the overlay, but by the
    // max of the thumb and the overlay, in case there is no overlay.
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width - overlayWidth;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    final PaintingContext context,
    final Offset offset, {
    required final RenderBox parentBox,
    required final SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required final Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required final Offset thumbCenter,
    required final TextDirection textDirection,
    final Offset? secondaryOffset,
    final bool isEnabled = true,
    final bool isDiscrete = true,
  }) {
    final Rect trackRectangle = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    
    const verticalOffset = const Offset(0, 20);

    context.canvas.drawPath(
        Path()
          ..addPolygon(
            [
              trackRectangle.bottomLeft - verticalOffset,
              trackRectangle.bottomRight,
              trackRectangle.topRight,
              trackRectangle.topLeft + verticalOffset,
              trackRectangle.bottomLeft - verticalOffset,
            ],
            true,
          ),
        Paint()..color = sliderTheme.activeTrackColor);
  }
}
```

#### CustomThumbShape()

```
class CustomThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  CustomThumbShape({
    this.thumbRadius = 15,
  });
  final double thumbRadius;
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(final bool isEnabled, final bool isDiscrete) =>
      Size.fromRadius(thumbWidth);

  @override
  void paint(
    final PaintingContext context,
    final Offset center, {
    required final Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required final Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required final RenderBox parentBox,
    required final Size sizeWithOverflow,
    required final SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required final TextDirection textDirection,
    required final TextPainter labelPainter,
    required final bool isDiscrete,
    required final double textScaleFactor,
    required final double value,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = sliderTheme.thumbColor;

    final TextSpan textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: value,
    );

    labelPainter
      ..text = textSpan
      ..textAlign = TextAlign.center
      ..textDirection = textDirection
      ..layout();

    final Offset textOffset = Offset(
      center.dx - (labelPainter.width / 2),
      center.dy + (sliderTheme.trackHeight! * 0.8),
    );

    final Offset p1 = Offset(
      center.dx,
      center.dy + sliderTheme.trackHeight! / 2,
    );
    final Offset p2 = Offset(
      center.dx,
      center.dy - sliderTheme.trackHeight! / 2,
    );

    canvas.drawCircle(center, thumbWidth, paint);
    if (isTouched) {
      labelPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        textOffset,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

you should also consider setting your slider colors and other theme properties in the *SliderThemeData*().